# Templated C++ class has an 'expected unqualified-id'

Tags: c++, templates, vector, stl, operator-overloading

For a class assignment we had to write the STL Vector in a templated .h file. I tried to run this and all of my member functions work except for the overloading of the assignment error. It's at the very bottom, it's the second to last member function.
When given the assignment I was asked to overload `Vector<T>& operator=(const Vector&v)`

```
template <class T>
class Vector{
    private:
    int current_size, capacity;
    T* arr;

    public:

    Vector();
    ~Vector();
    unsigned int size();
    void grow(); //where does this belong?
    void push_back(const T& elt);
    void pop_back();
    T& at(int pos);
    T& front();
    T& back();
    bool empty();
    void insert (const T&elt, int pos);
    void erase(int pos);
    Vector<T>& operator=(const Vector& v);
    T& operator[](int n);

    };

    template <class T>
    Vector<T>& Vector<T>::operator=(const Vector& v){
    current_size= v.size();
    capacity= v.capacity();
    }
```

**The error is "expected unqualified id" and the line with the error is:

 "Vector& Vector::operator=(const Vector& v)"{**

Comment: Why would you roll back the edit to make it less readable?

Comment: Sorry i just started using stackoverflow, I'm not good at this @NathanOliver

Comment: You should include the exact error message and point out the line where it happens.

Comment: @rodrigo judging by his code, I dont think he has an error message, I think he has a `Vector` that acts wierd at runtime

Comment: You say "The line with the error is `Vector& Vector::operator=(const Vector& v)`", however that line does not appear in your code. Your code actually has `Vector<T>& Vector<T>::operator=(const Vector& v)`. Please ensure to show the exact error message produced by the exact code you posted

Comment: The code you have posted compiles correctly for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many, many problems with this code.

Zeroth, your indendentation style makes it very hard to read the code. Every time you open a new scope, indent!

First, defining member functions:

```
template <class T>
typename Vector<T>::T& at(int pos)

template <class T>
Vector<T>:: T& back()
```

The correct syntax is `return-type class-name::member-name`. So these should be:

```
template <class T>
T& Vector<T>::at(int pos)

template <class T>
T& Vector<T>::back()
```

Second, `delete`-ing. `arr` is dynamic array to `T`. Only it is dynamic. In multiple places you are trying to delete individual elements:

```
delete arr[current_size-1];
```

That is an invalid operation.

Third, for your specific question, the parameter `v` is `const`:

```
template <class T>
Vector<T>& Vector<T>::operator=(const Vector<T>& v){
```

That means you can only call `const`-qualified member functions. `size()` is not `const`-qualified. You have to add:

```
unsigned int size() const;
                   ^^^^^^
```

After that, `capacity` is not a member function, it is just a member:

```
capacity= v.capacity();
                    ^^
```

After that, your copy assignment operator needs to actually copy all the elements too - otherwise it didn't really... copy anything of substance.

Comment: And not following the rule of 0/3/5.

Comment: template <class T>

Vector<T>::& operator=(const Vector& v){

    current_size=v.current_size;

    capacity=v.capacity;}

is this more accurate?
And can you clarify what you mean by copying things of substance

Comment: @Elina0524 Well, the vector is holding stuff right. If you're copying from another vector, you need to copy the "stuff" too.